# Question on whether limits pass into integrals

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\;f,g\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^2)\;$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{a \to
>  +\infty} f(a,b)=0\;,\lim_{c \to -\infty} f(c,b)=0\;$ .
>
> If I have to take limits as $\displaystyle a \to +\infty\;,c \to -\infty\;$ to
>   $\displaystyle \int_{c}^a f(a-x+c,y)+g(a-x+c,y)\;dx\;$ then is it right to claim
>   that:
>
> $$\displaystyle\lim_{c\to -\infty} \lim_{a\to +\infty}\int_{c}^a f(a-x+c,y)+g(a-x+c,y)\;dx=\\\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lim_{c\to -\infty}\lim_{a\to +\infty} g(a-x+c,y)\;dx\;$$

I think that if $\;f,g\;$ were independent of $\;a,c\;$ then the limits could pass into the integral since they are $\;\mathcal C^2\;$ functions on an interval, but what happens in this case confuses me a lot.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me through this because I've been stuck...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "the former one"?  I don't quite see what you mean.

Comment: @saulspatz I just edited it